# Kendo UI - Chart ValueAxis number format

Tags: vb.net, kendo-ui

[Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ4fF.png)

Hey there!
I'm having a problem with number formating using Kendo UI.

In the value axis, inside the red box, I want to use the "." as the thousands separator and "," as the decimal separator. The problem is that it is reversed, as it makes "," the thousands separator and "." as the decimal separator.

Below there is the block of code I'm using (VB:NET).

```
.ValueAxis(Sub(axis)
                                               axis.Numeric().Labels(Function(e)
                                                                         e.Format("{0:n6}")
                                                                         Return e
                                                                     End Function)

                                           End Sub)
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

valueAxis:{
    labels: {
      visible: true,
      template: "#= Math.abs(value) #"
    }
  }

Please see following page https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/valueaxis.labels